# jquery event handlers not working after redirecting and coming back to the same page to same frame

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have main page called main.aspx . In this i have 2 frames a.aspx and b.aspx
and code is

```
  <frameset rows="20%,80%">
    <frame name="b" src="b.aspx"/> 
    <frame name="a" src="a.aspx"/>        
  </frameset>
```

In a.aspx i have timer implementation with start and stop buttons and code is

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="txt1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td id="td1" runat="server">
            <p id="output" class="output">00:00:00</p>
            <div id="controls">
                <button id="startPause">Start</button>
                <button id="reset">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <a id="reload" href="demo.aspx"> **Another Demo** </a>
    <p id="p1"></p>
```

I have another demo page called demo.aspx which has redirecting link to a.aspx

in b.aspx, i have another timer to show in this frame

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1" runat="server">
            <p id="timer" class="displayNone">00:00:00</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this b.aspx, i have timer implementation code for both timers i.e timer in a.aspx and timer in b.aspx and javascript code of b.aspx

```
    var time = 0;
    var running = 0;
    var prevTdTxtBox;
    var temp = 0;
    var stopVal;
    var tdClientId;

  $("table", window.parent.frames['a'].document).on("click", "#startPause",     function () {
        startPause(this);
    });
  $("table", window.parent.frames['a'].document).on("click","#reset", function () {
        reset(this);
    }); 

function startPause(val) {
tdClientId = $(val).closest('td');
prevTdTxtBox = tdClientId.prev().find("input")[0].id;
$("#" + prevTdTxtBox, window.parent.frames['a'].document).val("00:00:00");
if (tdClientId[0].id != null) {
    if (running == 0) {
        running = 1;
        document.getElementById("timer").className = "output";
        increment(val);
        $("#" + val.id, window.parent.frames['a'].document).text("Pause");
    } else {

        running = 0;
        $("#" + val.id, window.parent.frames['a'].document).text("Resume");

    }
  }
}

function reset(val) {
   stopVal = val;
   running = 0;
   $("#p1", window.parent.frames['a'].document).text("The clock time is " +   temp + " secs");
   time = 0;
   $("#" + val.id, window.parent.frames['a'].document).prev().text("Start");
   var op = $("#" + $(val).closest('td').find('p')[0].id,
    window.parent.frames['a'].document).text();
   $("#" + prevTdTxtBox, window.parent.frames['a'].document).val(op);
   $("#" + $(val).closest('td').find('p')[0].id,
   window.parent.frames['a'].document).text("00:00:00");
   document.getElementById("timer").className = "displayNone";   
}

function increment(val) {
   if (running == 1) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        time++;
        var hrs = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60 / 60);
        var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
        var secs = Math.floor(time / 10 % 60);

        if (mins < 10) {
            mins = "0" + mins;
        }
        if (secs < 10) {
            secs = "0" + secs;
        }

        if (hrs < 10) {
            hrs = "0" + hrs;
        }
        temp = secs;
        var para = $(val).closest('td').find('p')[0].id;
        $("#" + para, window.parent.frames['a'].document).text(hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);            
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
        increment(val);

    }, 100);
   }
}
```

when i click on start both the timers in a.aspx and b.aspx are starting , pause and resume are also working fine here

The problem is that when i click on Another Demo link in a.aspx, it will redirect to demo.aspx and from demo.aspx i am redirecting to a.aspx using link in demo.aspx,

Now both timer are showing same time it seams they are working but when i try to click stop and start buttons they are not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you try referring the buttons onclick event to function like '<button id="startPause" onclick="startPause(val) ">Start</button>' ?

Comment: tried it but it did not work..

Comment: can yo let me know what is val in startPause(val)?

Comment: did you try having the js functions in the main.aspx page and then referring it with onclick event?